# How to show Folium HTML Plotly popup graphs on Flask? (Python)

Tags: python, html, flask, plotly, folium

I want to deploy a web map apps which containing several points and Plotly graphs as folium popup. Everything is fine until I want to deploy my web map apps in Flask, which when I click  the point, the pop up shows error message says

> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL
> manually please check your spelling and try again.

[image]

Here is the popup code

```
#make a dataframe which is used for plotting the well head point in folium
df_point = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(wells, html_list, Longitude, Latitude)), columns =['Well_Name', 'HTML_list', 'Longitude', 'Latitude'])

#Start plotting well head in map with well log plot as a pop up widget
for i in range(0,len(df_point)):
    html="""
    <iframe src=\"""" + df_point['HTML_list'][i] + """\" width="700" height="800"  frameborder="0">    
    """)
    
    popup = folium.Popup(folium.Html(html, script=True))
    
#     #Cirlce marker ver.
#     folium.CircleMarker([df_point['Latitude'].iloc[i],df_point['Longitude'].iloc[i]],
#                         popup=popup,radius=3.5,opacity=1,color='#ccd132').add_to(map1)
    
    #Marker with icon ver.
    folium.Marker([df_point['Latitude'].iloc[i],df_point['Longitude'].iloc[i]],
                  popup=popup,icon=folium.Icon( icon='glyphicon-pushpin')).add_to(map1)
```

I put the HTML file, coordinate and name on dataframe which is called `df_point`, here is the dataframes

```
    Well_Name    HTML_list      Longitude   Latitude
0   Well 1F   figWell 1F.html   96.083956   5.456862
1   Well 2F   figWell 2F.html   96.356427   5.328133
```

and here is my Flask `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def render_the_map():
    return render_template('testing_map.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and also here is the path if someone need my file path information

[image]

How do I put the Plotly graphs in HTML format as pop up folium on Flask? I'm still new in Flask development. Any help I would appreciate it, Thanks!

Comment: I feel you missundestood the use of an `<iframe>` Html tag, from what i can tell you are passing a dataframe as source `src="XX + df_point['HTML_list'][i] + XX`, A data farme spects a source of HTML code and you are passing raw data. What you can do is create a new route in Flask that returns the HTML code that renders your plot, and use `url_for('plot_view')` as the src parameter in the iframe code.

Comment: can you give me example of how to create new route in Flask that returns HTML code, and use url_for('plot_view') in iframe code? I'm really new in Flask and I'm getting confused by your comment, thanku for the response! @SebastianSalinasDelRio

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution, I tried googling to find what you mean and it works! thank you so much dude @SebastianSalinasDelRio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on Sebastian's answer, if someone want to make a Folium map and the pop up marker showing plotly html in Flask, here's how to do it

first, in the `app.py`, make a route for the plotly plot

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def render_the_map():
    return render_template('testing_map.html')

@app.route('/figure1')
def figure_plotly1():
    return render_template('figWell 1F.html')

@app.route('/figure2')
def figure_plotly2():
    return render_template('figWell 2F.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and then, search your plotly code in your folium map html and change the iframe source to the defined route, so for example, my plotly html graph name is `figWell 1F.html`, try to ctrl+F in your main HTML folium map and change the iframe src to be like this

```
<iframe src="{{url_for('figure_plotly1')}}" width="700" height="800"
```

and it works like a charm